# How to get Service name and status

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to capture service name and status for 3 services. With

```
sc query "MpsSvc"
```

It gives service name, type, status and other info.

With `sc query "MPSSvc| find "STATUS"`

out put doesn't show Service name.

My query is to get service name and status for "MpsSvc" , "ctmag" and "Dhcp" services.

How to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in ("MpsSvc" , "ctmag" , "Dhcp" ) do ( 
  @echo|set /p=%%a  
  @sc query "%%~a" | find "STATE"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sc query "MPSSvc" | findstr "STATUS SERVICE_NAME"
```

Comment: I think there's a missing quote after MPSSvc

Comment: I attempted to run this but I only get `SERVICE_NAME: "xxxx"` back. I don't get the status as well. Could you assist? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic service get name,state | findstr /i "mpssvc dtmag dhcp"
```